# Laravel update some database row

Tags: laravel-5

I create a page that update some data in database :

```
    public function postedit(Requests\editRequest $request)
{
    $upgrade = DB::table('upgrade')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->update($request->all());


}
```

when i fill form i get this error :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 725:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field 
list' (SQL: update `upgrade` set `_token` = 
g6MudghCdVvtL0ir361h9ysx53gRnv227LKSSZIz, `tell` = 867136819, `mobile` = 
316136135, `Address` = usa-ny, `zip_code` = 141515 where `user_id` = 
19)
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including a csrf token in your form input hence the  `_token` field is added to the request. You can take **only** some fields from the request like:

```
$input = Request::only('tell',
'mobile',
'Address',
'zip_code');

$upgrade = DB::table('upgrade')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->update($input);
```

Comment: i get this error when use this code
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except()

Comment: @Sina Maafi what all fields do you have in request?

Comment: @SinaMaafi I have updated my answer please check again